# how to correctly merge several feature to main branch

Tags: git

Here I have a question.
I have a `main` branch and 2 feature branches `feature1` and `feature2` which is checkout from `main`, when I finished developing these features, I want them to merge into `main`.

So I checkout a new branche named `merge` from `main`, and see what is going on after mergeing `feature1` and `feature2` yesterday. And from IDEA, it can be seen these 3 branches like this:

[image]

brown line is `merge`

green line is `feature1`

blue line is `feature2`

After testing, today I decided to merge `feature1` and `feature2` into another `main`'s branch in **exactly the same method(checkout a new branch from `main` and merge `feature1` and `feature2`)**, but found this strange thing... IDEA showed the branch lines in quite an unapropriate way which like this:

[image]

No matter how I change the order of merging `feature1` and `feature2` it won't help, the branch line graph will always wrong.
I don't know why this happening.Is there anything wrong with my merging movement?

I didn't touch my code at all,and no new commits at all, just checkout 2 new branches from `main` in different days, and doing the same merging process.

Comment: It's kinda hard to understand what your problem is (figure 2 looks like what I'd expect - your `feature 1` starts from commit on `merge` after `feature 2`). Perhaps you want to merge `feature 2` first and then rebase `feature1` on top of `merge` and  merge it?

Comment: @blami No,I was just wondering, `feature1` and `feature2` was started from `main`, and `merge` is a branch starts from `main` and is quite the same as `main`, but why `feature1` and `feature2` can merge back to `merge` as figure1 shows but merge back to `main` as figure2 shows?`main` and `merge` are the same, and figure1 should be the right merge which was created and merged yesterday.

Comment: @blami Also, I merged `merge` into `main`, the problem was solved and the branch lines showed in IDEA was the same as figure1 which I'm expected.  `feature1` and `feature2` just cannot merge into `main` directly which I just did so in `merge`.

Comment: @blami I don't know if it is because `merge` was created yesterday, which is before lastet commits in `feature1` and `feature2`. That confuzed me a lot...

Comment: The commits are cutoff, but from what I see both graphs look identical... (If you think they are different, then you may be assigning meaning to something that has no meaning.)

Comment: @TTT Yes, I agree with you. I know they are the same by manual checking. But they shows totally different from each other through command `git diff` which will lead to some misunderstanding when others reviewing my code. I don't know what caused this situation nor how to avoid this situation in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest always rebase before merging, so further merge will be just fast-forward and branch tree will be nice and clean. First, finish work on your `feature1`, then checkout on it and execute `git rebase master`, resolve conflict, if presented. Then checkout on main branch and merge `feature1`: `git merge feature1`. Then do the same for `feature2`: `git checkout feature2`, `git rebase master`, `git checkout master`, `git merge feature2`.
Notice that this process better start from clean branches, not already messed-up.